# How to correctly provide CRUD repository to be able to view and create data in DB (I'm getting error with beans)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I started studying programming with Java and face the problem I can't resolve for couple of days. I use JDK-13 and Spring Boot 2.4.4, and when I try to add CRUD Repository in my project and launch the server, I get an error:

```
Description:

Field noteRepo in com.javatechnologies.zettelkasten.MainController required a bean of type 'com.javatechnologies.zettelkasten.NoteRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.javatechnologies.zettelkasten.NoteRepository' in your configuration.
```

**Additional info and link to a github repository provided below. If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful**

I have a db model:

```
@Entity
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String tag;

    // empty constructor for spring model generation
    public Note(){
    }

    public Note(String title, String text, String tag){
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and repository for this one:

```
package com.javatechnologies.zettelkasten;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface NoteRepository extends CrudRepository<Note, Long> {}
```

And now I try to use this repository in my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private NoteRepository noteRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String mainPaige(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Iterable<Note> notes = noteRepo.findAll();

        model.put("notes", notes);
        return "mainPage";
    }
...
```

If you need additional information, you can got to the repository on github: https://github.com/OlegYariga/zettelkasten

Comment: `NoteRepository` must be annotated with `@Repository`

Comment: @Jens Annotation with @Repository does not fixes the error. I tried to add `@Repository` instead of `@Component` and tried to add both `@Component` and `@Repository` - it doesn't  affect an error

Comment: @ЯригаОлег when extending crudrepository also fix the generics. It must be `CrudRepository<Note, Integer>`. The second generic is the type of id. And you have it as Integer not Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are tring touse JAP, you miss the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your pom:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And you have to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ZettelkastenApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZettelkastenApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And annotate the repository with `@Repository`

Comment: all is needed is the dependency: "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa". `EnableJpaRepositories` is not necessary as well as adding `@Repository` annotation, because by extending the `CrudRepository` you already say to spring to create a bean

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot! It solved my problem.